# Probability of a given 3 teams playing each other in 1st round

Tags: probability

There are 10 total teams in a company volleyball tournament and 3 of them are from the same department, let's just call it the finance department. What is the probability that two teams from the finance department will face each other in the first round?

This is a seemingly simple probability problem that was posed to me. I found a solution with a spreadsheet simulation that I believe is correct, but I haven't been able to replicate it with an elegant analytical solution that makes sense to me.

Comment: How does the tournament work?  I expected `2^n  `teams.

Comment: I'm not sure how the rest of the tournament plays out, but we are only looking at the first round here. 10 teams = 5 matches

Answer (score 4):

It is 1 minus the probability of none of the teams playing each other. Now, I assume that there are 5 games in the first round where the 10 teams are randomly paired to play against each other. So, given that there are 5 games, after the 'first' of the three teams is given a slot, there is an 8 in 9 chance that the 'second' team does not play the 'first', and once that has happened, there is a 6 in 8 chance that the 'third' team does not play either the first or second.

So, there is a $\frac{8}{9} \cdot \frac{6}{8}=\frac{2}{3}$ chance none of them meet, and hence a $\frac{1}{3}$ chance that some of them will meet.

Comment: Seems like you should use 7/9 first. ..

Comment: @ChrisCuster After the first team is placed, there are 9 slots left, and only 1 of them is the slot that plays against the first team, so it really is $\frac{8}{9}$

Comment: I still think  $\frac 79$.  There are two teams to avoid.

Comment: @ChrisCuster The third team to be placed has to avoid two teams, yes, but at that point there are only 8 slots left, so that 's the $\frac{6}{8}$.  The second team to be placed merely has to avoid playing against the first.

Comment: @ChrisCuster there are two ways of looking at it. Either you check A doesn't play B, and then check C doesn't play A or B (Bram's way), or you check A doesn't play B or C and then check B doesn't play C (your way). They're both correct: one gives $\frac89\times\frac68$ and the other gives $\frac79\times\frac67$, and these are equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

$\frac79$ ways for the second team to be chosen if the first is set.  $\frac67$ ways to avoid a meeting once the second team is set.  $\frac79×\frac67=\frac23$.  Take the complement :  $1-\frac23=\frac13$.

Answer (score 1):

How I did it.

Lets call the three teams from finance $F_1,F_2, F_3$

There are 9 teams that team F_1 could match with two of which are in finance.

$F_1$ matches with another finance team $\frac 29$
$F_1$ does not match with another finance team $\frac 79$

If $F_1$ does not match with a finance team what is the chance $F_2$ matches with $F_3?$

There are $7$ teams $F_2$ could be matched with.  One of which is $F_3$

$\frac 29 + \frac 79\cdot\frac 17 = \frac 13$

Answer (score 0):

$\boxed.\boxed.\quad\boxed.\boxed.\quad\boxed.\boxed.\quad\boxed.\boxed.\quad\boxed.\boxed.\quad$

If the three are to avoid each other, they can be placed in $10\cdot8\cdot6$ ways,

so P(they don't meet) = $\dfrac{10\cdot8\cdot6}{10\cdot9\cdot8} = \dfrac23$

and P(they meet) $=\dfrac13$